# How to overwrite the category template in a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, archives, archive-template

So I basically need to overwrite my category template in my child theme with the one in my plugin but I can't seem to get it working.

I have checked the files paths and everything and there all correct this seems to be the way of doing it but again Wordpress doesn't seem to be using the template from my plugin.

```
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'load_new_custom_tax_template');
function load_new_custom_tax_template ($tax_template) {
  if (is_category()) {
    $tax_template = dirname(  __FILE__  ) . '/category.php';
  }
  return $tax_template;
}
```

Comment: If that’s your main plug-in file, and your plugins category.php template is in the same directory try Wordpress `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ) . “category.php”` instead of php’s `dirname`.

Comment: @BenHartLenn Yes it is in the main plugin directory, I did try the above but unfortunately, no luck its still not using the template in the plugin.

Comment: @IbrarrKhan did using `category_template` or `template_include` work for you? If not, what solution you used?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) in your function, which means you're targetting the default/core `category` taxonomy and not a *custom* taxonomy, hence you should instead use the `category_template` hook. E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'category_template', 'load_new_custom_tax_template');
function load_new_custom_tax_template ($tax_template) {
    // I don't check for is_category() because we're using the category_template filter.
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/category.php';
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`template_include` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) which runs ***after*** the [`<type>_template` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/) such as the `category_template` and `taxonomy_template`:

```php
add_filter( 'template_include', 'load_new_custom_tax_template');
function load_new_custom_tax_template ($tax_template) {
    if (is_category()) {
        $tax_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/category.php';
    }
    return $tax_template;
}
```

Note though, other plugins can also override the template, hence you might want to use a lower priority, i.e. a greater number as the 3rd parameter for `add_filter()`. E.g. 20 as in `add_filter( 'category_template', 'load_new_custom_tax_template', 20)`